# How to alt tab to 'about this mac'?

Tags: macos

This window does not have a tab, so once you alt tab away you can't alt tab back. Is there actually a way that I do not know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cmd-tab to it since it is not an application. The best you can do via keyboard commands is to use Cmd+Space to bring up spotlight, then start typing "About this Mac", once it populates, hit Enter.